# How to add a custom date validation error message in Yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I have a field in a Formik form which is a date.  In the Yup validation schema I have set this field to Yup.date() validation, as follows:

```
  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    deceased: Yup.date(),
```

This Formik field is returned with:

```
        <Form className="formContainer">
          <div className="pb-2">
            <label>Deactivate Member Record</label>
            <ErrorMessage name="deceased" component="span" className="text-red-500" />
            <Field
              autoComplete="off"
              id="inputCreateMember"
              name="deceased"
              placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
            />
```

If the date isn't enterd in the yyyy-mm-dd format, it displays a validation error in the format:

[field name] must be a `date` type, but the final value was 'Invalid Date' cast from value `"[value entered in the form field]"`

For example, I entered '20' in the date field below labelled 'Deactivate Member Record' and got the following validation error:

[Example of validation error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1C4vi.png)

I don't want users to see this complicated error message though, instead I just want to reiterate to them that they need to use the date format yyyy-mm-dd.

I know I can customise the error message using .typeError() but that also results in the validation occurring multiple times; once every time a character is entered in the field.  This is also not satisfactory, I just want the validation error message to appear when the user exits the field, similar to how custom error messages can be displayed with the .required() validation type.

Comment: In the end I couldn't resolve this with yup, so I deactived yup for this field and used the react-number-format package on it insetad, and specifically its PatternFormat function of that package which allows various date format validations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved using the PatternFormat functionality from the react-number-format component.

Code:

```
    <PatternFormat
      {...field}
      format="####/##/##"
      mask={['Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'M', 'M', 'D', 'D']}
      className={formikField}
      placeholder="YYYY/MM/DD"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

As yup’s API reference say: it date type only have two validation(min or max).

I don’t know why you have this format error message.

But I think you can use custom validation:

```js
const yupDate = (name) => yup.date().test({
  name,
  test(value, ctx) {
    const isValid = ...
    if (!isValid) {
      return ctx.createError({message: "date is not satisfied YYYY/MM/DD format"})
    }
    return true
  }
})
```